# How to do \flushleft and \flushright with tikzpictures

Tags: pgfplots, horizontal-alignment, pgf-pie

I have two charts, one is drawn with `pgfplots`, the other with `pgf-pie`. I want put these two chart in align horizontally, so one is on the left and the other is on the right. I have read [Aligning using flushleft and flushright](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116779/aligning-using-flushleft-and-flushright), but it seems this `minipage` trick does not work in my case.

This is an example. I expected the two charts stand side-by-side, but they are not. About the *width* of the `minipage`, I tried many values. Maybe I don't understand it correctly.

```
\begin{minipage}{0.5 \linewidth}
\begin{flushleft}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    title=\# of players in a class,
    ybar,
    %enlargelimits=0.15,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},
      anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ylabel={Population},
    symbolic x coords={Warrior,Wizard,Archer},
    xtick=data,
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
    x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
  ]
    \addplot coordinates {(Warrior,100) (Wizard,100) (Archer,200)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{0.5 \linewidth}
\begin{flushright}
Ratio of players in a class
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pie{ 25/ \textsc{Warrior} , 25/ \textsc{Wizard} , 50/ \textsc{Archer} }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: Hi, just to be sure, you want them both side by side? Can you prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to give us some starting point to work with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `minipage` trick still does work, but

1. you have spurious spaces (and a paragraph!) between the minipages, so they don't end up side-by-side and
2. the figures are too large to fit in boxes of width `0.5\linewidth`.

To fix Problem 1: Remove the newlines and add comments at ends of lines to suppress spurious spaces. You also need to add `\hfill` between the `minipages` as in the linked solution.

To fix Problem 2: You can adjust the `width` key in the `axis` environment to change the size of the plot. You can also use the `scale` option to the `tikzpicture` to adjust the size of the pie chart.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgf-pie,lipsum}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\fboxsep=0pt % just for showing minipage size

\begin{document}\noindent
\fbox{% just to show minipage size
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45 \linewidth}% just slightly shrunk to show the separation
\begin{flushleft}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    title=\# of players in a class,
    ybar,
    width=5cm, % adjust here
    enlargelimits=0.25,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},
      anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ylabel={Population},
    symbolic x coords={Warrior,Wizard,Archer},
    xtick=data,
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
    x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
  ]
    \addplot coordinates {(Warrior,100) (Wizard,100) (Archer,200)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}}\hfill%
\fbox{% just to show minipage size
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45 \linewidth}% just slightly shrunk to show the separation
\begin{flushright}
Ratio of players in a class
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]% adjust scale parameter
  \pie{ 25/ \textsc{Warrior} , 25/ \textsc{Wizard} , 50/ \textsc{Archer} }
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{flushright}%
\end{minipage}}%

\lipsum[1-2] % just to show margins
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can remove the `\fbox`es for your own usage; I've just used them here to show the size of the `minipage`s.

Comment: @davidshen84 did you see the `width=5cm, % adjust here` line in the options to the `axis` environment in my example?